# Strange Owl carousel behaviour

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, owl-carousel

I have been trying to fix owl carousel for days now and cant find any online solution that would help me. Maybe you as web gurus can help me out :).

I am loading the owl CSS at head tag. Then at the bottom Im loading this:

```
<script src="assets/plugins/owl-carousel2/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/plugins/owl-carousel2.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
  App.init();
  OwlCarousel.initOwlCarousel();
  ContactForm.initContactForm();
  CirclesMaster.initCirclesMaster();
  ProgressBar.initProgressBarHorizontal();
  new WOW().init();
});
</script>
```

And Im getting this, its vertical instead of horizontal and obviously there are some problems in there. Just cant work out what it is...

[image]

Comment: The carousel is not initialized at all

Comment: How can i initialise it?

Comment: Try using google chrome console to check for any js error

Comment: No error at all....

Comment: As Allan said check for errors

Comment: Can u add the init code

Comment: If the answer below didn't work for you, try giving us the whole code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If no error found in console, check the net tab to see if all external files are loaded properly.

Make sure you have added init code like the people in comments have said - check the javascript tab from example here - http://www.owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/images.html

If you still don't get proper output, try adding this below your init lines to see if carousel is getting initialised properly -

```
var owl = $(".your-selector-here").data('owlCarousel');
console.log(owl);
```